# Query to fill in Null fields with maximum value based on other fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access, relational-database

I have a table with three fields: **A, B, C.**

- **A** is comprised of integer values;
- For **each** integer in A, **B** has integers 0-65 such that the total number of rows is **A * 66**;
- For **each** A-B combination, there is a corresponding decimal number in **C**, increasing as B increases.
- However, for Each A there are a different number of C's; All the records without a corresponding C Value are **NULL**

I was wondering how to create a query such that the **NULL C records** for each **A** are filled in with the **C** value that corresponds to the highest **B**.

- For Example: for **A = 1**, We have **16 distinct C values** for **B = 0 through 15**.

  - For A = 1 and B = 16 through 65, I want to fill in the C value that corresponds to B = 15 (Highest B value).

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 as DBMS

Comment: It is a lot of talk. Prepare sample input/output + http://www.sqlfiddle.com data so someone can help.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up lad2025:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd7d0

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? You tagged sql server and Access. Then you posted a fiddle for mysql. These are three independent products and they are not the same thing.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

**[SQLFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d231c/12)**

```
;WITH cte (A, highest_c)
AS
(
   SELECT
      A,
      highest = MAX(C)
   FROM ALinQ1
   GROUP BY A
)
UPDATE tab
SET C = c.highest_c
FROM ALinQ1 tab
INNER JOIN cte c
  ON tab.a = c.a
WHERE tab.C IS NULL
    AND tab.B <> 0;
```

Comment: @AlexLin Tell also what to do with rows `A=1 B=0, A=2, B=0` and so on, should stay null or get max?

Comment: Those rows can stay null. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AlexLin Ok, they will be null.